# UITextalignment is deprecated : You should use setTextAlignment:lineBreakMode:on your NSAttributedString instead

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel

I am using OHAttributeLabel in my iPhone Application but now I am getting an warning

```
UITextAlignment is deprecated : You should use setTextAlignment:lineBreakMode:on your NSAttributedString instead
```

Please anyone suggest me how to resolve it.

Comment: By using `NSAttributedString` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// suppose that label is an IBOutlet to an OHAttributedLabel (subclass oh UILabel)

```
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentJustify;
```

// and that's all, OHAttributedLabel does everything needed for you!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

its work